# Combining 2 (or 3) Javascripts when both use an ID

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I'm just in the process of learning HTML and JS and have the need to combine two functions - both work on their own. I have browsed through the suggestions, and tried about 3 different methods,  but I still can't work it out.
I have a link that exposes a hidden div when clicked and I now need the text to change to "Close" … default is closed and text says open. Both the JavaScript work on their own.
I cannot use external files with this.

My question is:

How do I get the 3 functions below to work from the one link?

JavaScript file 1

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if(e.style.display == 'none')
    e.style.display = 'block';
    else
    e.style.display = 'none';
}
```

JavaScript file 2

```
function openTri() {
    document.getElementById('tri').innerHTML = "<a href='javascript:cloTri()'>Open</a>";
}
function cloTri() {
    document.getElementById('tri').innerHTML = "<a href='javascript:openTri()'>Close;</a>";
}
```

Comment: I'm not really sure there is a question here? What exactly is going wrong in the code?

Comment: You want to combine 2 functions, ok. But there is 3 functions here...

Comment: what does the contents of the first file have to do with the second? that toggle_visibility function doesn't appear to be called to from the second file.

the second file looks like it should work fine the way it is - what do you mean 'the one link?' do you want one link to call one function, and have the function determine whether to open/close?

Comment: it's all meant to be just one file - a summary line with a toggle for the detail. When I click on the link then I need the div to appear, and the text to change also. I posted them seperately as they work seperately . I tried merging them, but nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing at what you want to do but might be this

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if(e.style.display == 'none') {
        e.style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('tri').innerHTML = "<a href='javascript:openTri()'>Close;</a>";
    }
    else {
        e.style.display = 'none';
         document.getElementById('tri').innerHTML = "<a href='javascript:cloTri()'>Open</a>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually - that's it ! Many thanks - I did try something similar, but my element had the same id - one of the most elementary errors possible… Many thanks and sorry to have wasted your time